# How to convert row to column on specific condition using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file while I want to convert from row to column on specific condition.

Input file:

```
cat f
"0/35","0eij8401c
"0/35","59ij41015
"0/35","21ij3e01c
"0/35","dbije401b
"1/35","dbij8a015
"1/35","67ijb9011
"1/35","b5ije001b
"1/35","bdij3701d
"2/35","abij3b011
"2/35","7fij70018
"2/35","77ijf9010
"2/35","e5ij64015
"3/35","59ij41015
"3/35","f6ijae01e
"3/35","c4ij5801c
"3/35","dbij98012
"4/35","edij6801e
"4/35","pdij6801e
"4/35","kdij6801e
"4/35","8cij57018
```

NOTE: here I am fetching 1st, 5th, 9th, 13th and 17th row's second column in first column in output below. like wise 2nd, 6th, 10th, 14th and 18th row's second column to print second column in output and same for rest of the rows.

There are two expected output:

Expected output 1: (To see it in a report format)

```
"0eij8401c  "dbij8a015  "abij3b011  "59ij41015  "edij6801e
"59ij41015  "67ijb9011  "7fij70018  "f6ijae01e  "pdij6801e
"21ij3e01c  "b5ije001b  "77ijf9010  "c4ij5801c  "kdij6801e
"dbije401b  "bdij3701d  "e5ij64015  "dbij98012  "8cij57018
```

Expected output2:
And then convert the expected output1 into a single column to perform some operation:

```
0eij8401c
dbij8a015
abij3b011
59ij41015
edij6801e
59ij41015
67ijb9011
7fij70018
f6ijae01e
pdij6801e
21ij3e01c
b5ije001b
77ijf9010
c4ij5801c
kdij6801e
dbije401b
bdij3701d
e5ij64015
dbij98012
8cij57018
```

I tried combination of awk and paste, trying to achieve both with awk command.
This is what I tried -

```
cat f | awk -v batchNo=1 -v Num=4 '{print $1 > "batch_" batchNo ".txt";if(NR%Num==0) {batchNo++}}'
```

to generate 5 files like below -

```
ls batch_*
batch_1.txt  batch_2.txt  batch_3.txt  batch_4.txt  batch_5.txt
```

and then combined with paste like below -

```
 paste batch_1.txt batch_2.txt batch_3.txt batch_4.txt batch_5.txt
"0eij8401c  "dbij8a015  "abij3b011  "59ij41015  "edij6801e
"59ij41015  "67ijb9011  "7fij70018  "f6ijae01e  "pdij6801e
"21ij3e01c  "b5ije001b  "77ijf9010  "c4ij5801c  "kdij6801e
"dbije401b  "bdij3701d  "e5ij64015  "dbij98012  "8cij57018
```

I also tried something like this to get the desired result but didn't get it.

```
awk '{a[$1]++; b[$2]++;c[$3]++;d[$4]++;e[$5]++} END {for (k in a) print k > "out.txt"; for (j in b) print j > "out.txt";for (k in c) print j > "out.txt";for(l in d) print l> "out.txt"; for (m in e) print m> "out.txt";}' batch_*
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts(with code) keep it up. You have shown 2 expected output in your question, could you please confirm if 2nd output after line `and then combined with paste like below` is the one you required? If not then request you to edit your question(keep the code part in it only edit samples of input and output), cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Thanks for your response, I have updated the question. There are two expected output which I am looking for.

Comment: Are you asking for "Expected Output 1" because you think you need it to get Expected Output 2 or do you actually have some other purpose for Expected Output 1 beyond just that? Do you **really** want to have the `"`s in Expected Output 1?

Comment: Yeah! I do have some other purpose for expected output1 and need both expected output1 and output2. `"` is not really important here.

Comment: You are commiting a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use of `cat`*, also stated as *Useless Use of `cat`*). Whenever you do `cat file ...` and are not concatenating files, it is a *UUOc*. Instead, `awk '{....}' f`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR, Sure thanks for confirming, I have updated 3 of my answers with complete details now as per your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\"" }
{ vals[++numVals] = $NF }
END {
    numValsPerBatch = int(numVals / numBatches) + ( numVals % numBatches ? 1 : 0 )

    for ( batchNr=1; batchNr<=numBatches; batchNr++ ) {
        for ( valNr=1; valNr<=numValsPerBatch; valNr++ ) {
            valIdx = batchNr + (valNr - 1) * numBatches
            printf "%s%s", vals[valIdx], (valNr<numValsPerBatch ? OFS : ORS) > "out1.txt"
            print vals[valIdx] > "out2.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v numBatches=4 -f tst.awk f
```

```
$ head -100 out?.txt
==> out1.txt <==
0eij8401c dbij8a015 abij3b011 59ij41015 edij6801e
59ij41015 67ijb9011 7fij70018 f6ijae01e pdij6801e
21ij3e01c b5ije001b 77ijf9010 c4ij5801c kdij6801e
dbije401b bdij3701d e5ij64015 dbij98012 8cij57018

==> out2.txt <==
0eij8401c
dbij8a015
abij3b011
59ij41015
edij6801e
59ij41015
67ijb9011
7fij70018
f6ijae01e
pdij6801e
21ij3e01c
b5ije001b
77ijf9010
c4ij5801c
kdij6801e
dbije401b
bdij3701d
e5ij64015
dbij98012
8cij57018
```

or if you want the number of batches to be calculated from the key values (YMMV if there's different numbers of values per key in your input):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\"" }
!seen[$2]++ { numKeys++ }
{ vals[++numVals] = $NF }
END {
    numBatches = int(numVals / numKeys) + (numVals % numKeys ? 1 : 0)
    numValsPerBatch = int(numVals / numBatches) + (numVals % numBatches ? 1 : 0)

    for ( batchNr=1; batchNr<=numBatches; batchNr++ ) {
        for ( valNr=1; valNr<=numValsPerBatch; valNr++ ) {
            valIdx = batchNr + (valNr - 1) * numBatches
            printf "%s%s", vals[valIdx], (valNr<numValsPerBatch ? OFS : ORS) > "out1.txt"
            print vals[valIdx] > "out2.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk f
```

```
$ head -100 out?.txt
==> out1.txt <==
0eij8401c dbij8a015 abij3b011 59ij41015 edij6801e
59ij41015 67ijb9011 7fij70018 f6ijae01e pdij6801e
21ij3e01c b5ije001b 77ijf9010 c4ij5801c kdij6801e
dbije401b bdij3701d e5ij64015 dbij98012 8cij57018

==> out2.txt <==
0eij8401c
dbij8a015
abij3b011
59ij41015
edij6801e
59ij41015
67ijb9011
7fij70018
f6ijae01e
pdij6801e
21ij3e01c
b5ije001b
77ijf9010
c4ij5801c
kdij6801e
dbije401b
bdij3701d
e5ij64015
dbij98012
8cij57018
```

Answer (score 3):

***About solutions:*** 3 of these solutions will print continuous view(details one by one for file's continuity) AND report view as well where you need them horizontally. 1st solution: considers that your Input_file is sorted by `digits/digits` format. 2nd solution sorts Input_file then does the job. 3rd: solution print both styles and create output file batches also.

---

---

***1st solution:*** (Considers that your Input_file is sorted by `"digit/digits"` format)With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. This will print the output directly sorting order of 1st field eg: `"0/35"`, `"1/35"` and so on.

```bash
awk -v count=0 -v s1="\"" -F'^"|","'  '
prev!=$2{
  countFile++
  max=(max>count?max:count)
  count=1
}
{
  arr[countFile,count++]=$3
  prev=$2
}
END{
 print "Printing continous view from here..."
 for(i=1;i<=max;i++){
     for(j=1;j<countFile;j++){
        print(arr[i,j])
     }
  }
  print "Printing REPORT view from here......"
  for(i=1;i<countFile;i++){
     for(j=1;j<=max;j++){
        printf("%s%s",s1 arr[j,i],j==max?ORS:OFS)
     }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case your Input_file is NOT sorted with(`"digit/digits"` format) then try this code.

```bash
awk -F'^"|","' '{print $2,$0}' Input_file | sort -t/ -nk1 -k2 | cut -d' ' -f2 |
awk -v count=0 -v s1="\"" -F'^"|","'  '
prev!=$2{
  countFile++
  max=(max>count?max:count)
  count=1
}
{
  arr[countFile,count++]=$3
  prev=$2
}
END{
 print "Printing continous view from here..."
 for(i=1;i<=max;i++){
     for(j=1;j<countFile;j++){
        print(arr[i,j])
     }
  }
  print "Printing REPORT view from here......"
  for(i=1;i<countFile;i++){
     for(j=1;j<=max;j++){
        printf("%s%s",s1 arr[j,i],j==max?ORS:OFS)
     }
  }
}
'
```

---

---

***OR 3rd solution:*** In case you want to print data on screen as well as you want to create output files also within same `awk` program then try following:

```bash
awk -v count=0 -v s1="\"" -F'^"|","'  '
prev!=$2{
  close(outputFile)
  countFile++
  outputFile="batch_"countFile".txt"
  max=(max>count?max:count)
  count=1
}
{
  arr[countFile,count++]=$3
  prev=$2
  print (s1 $3) > (outputFile)
}
END{
 print "Printing continous view from here..."
 for(i=1;i<=max;i++){
     for(j=1;j<countFile;j++){
        print(arr[i,j])
     }
  }
  print "Printing REPORT view from here......"
  for(i=1;i<countFile;i++){
     for(j=1;j<=max;j++){
        printf("%s%s",s1 arr[j,i],j==max?ORS:OFS)
     }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows which it will print:

```
"0eij8401c "dbij8a015 "abij3b011 "59ij41015 "edij6801e
"59ij41015 "67ijb9011 "7fij70018 "f6ijae01e "pdij6801e
"21ij3e01c "b5ije001b "77ijf9010 "c4ij5801c "kdij6801e
"dbije401b "bdij3701d "e5ij64015 "dbij98012 "8cij57018
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other two good answers, there is yet another simplified way to approach each of your separate output problems. In the first case, you can simply save the values from the second column in an indexed array and then output in rows by groups of 5, e.g.

```bash
awk -F, '
  {  a[++n] = $2 } 
  END {
    for (i=1; i<=(n/5); i++)
      printf "%s  %s  %s  %s  %s\n", a[i], a[i+4], a[i+8], a[i+12], a[i+16]
  }
' f
```

**Output**

```
"0eij8401c  "dbij8a015  "abij3b011  "59ij41015  "edij6801e
"59ij41015  "67ijb9011  "7fij70018  "f6ijae01e  "pdij6801e
"21ij3e01c  "b5ije001b  "77ijf9010  "c4ij5801c  "kdij6801e
"dbije401b  "bdij3701d  "e5ij64015  "dbij98012  "8cij57018
```

If you need the column output in the specific order shown, you can use the approach to save to an indexed array and then output with `'\n'` separators instead along with trimming the first char with `substr()`, e.g.

```bash
awk -F, '
  {  a[++n]=$2 }
  END {
    for (i=1; i<=(n/5); i++)
      printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", substr(a[i],2), substr(a[i+4],2), 
              substr(a[i+8],2), substr(a[i+12],2), substr(a[i+16],2) 
  }
' f
```

**Output**

```
0eij8401c
dbij8a015
abij3b011
59ij41015
edij6801e
59ij41015
67ijb9011
7fij70018
f6ijae01e
pdij6801e
21ij3e01c
b5ije001b
77ijf9010
c4ij5801c
kdij6801e
dbije401b
bdij3701d
e5ij64015
dbij98012
8cij57018
```

If you just need a column of output of the 2nd field, regardless of order, you can simply use substring to output all but the first character, e.g.

```bash
awk -F, '{ print substr($2,2) }' f
```

**Output**

```
0eij8401c
59ij41015
21ij3e01c
dbije401b
dbij8a015
67ijb9011
b5ije001b
bdij3701d
abij3b011
7fij70018
77ijf9010
e5ij64015
59ij41015
f6ijae01e
c4ij5801c
dbij98012
edij6801e
pdij6801e
kdij6801e
8cij57018
```

Answer (score 2):

As your shown input is already sorted on first field, you may use this solution:

```bash
awk -F, '{gsub(/^"|\/[0-9]+"/, ""); print $2 > "batch_" ($1+1) ".txt"}' f

paste batch_1.txt batch_2.txt batch_3.txt batch_4.txt batch_5.txt

"0eij8401c  "dbij8a015  "abij3b011  "59ij41015  "edij6801e
"59ij41015  "67ijb9011  "7fij70018  "f6ijae01e  "pdij6801e
"21ij3e01c  "b5ije001b  "77ijf9010  "c4ij5801c  "kdij6801e
"dbije401b  "bdij3701d  "e5ij64015  "dbij98012  "8cij57018
```

---

For output2 as per edited question use:

```bash
awk '{
   a[FNR] = a[FNR] substr($0,2) "\n"
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=FNR; ++i) printf "%s", a[i]
}' batch_1.txt batch_2.txt batch_3.txt batch_4.txt batch_5.txt

0eij8401c
dbij8a015
abij3b011
59ij41015
edij6801e
59ij41015
67ijb9011
7fij70018
f6ijae01e
pdij6801e
21ij3e01c
b5ije001b
77ijf9010
c4ij5801c
kdij6801e
dbije401b
bdij3701d
e5ij64015
dbij98012
8cij57018
```

Comment: Always liked the way `paste` simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

[TXR](https://nongnu.org.txr) solution:

```
@(collect)
@  (all)
"@id/@nil
@  (and)
@    (collect :gap 0)
"@id/@nil","@data
@      (bind qdata `"@data`)
@    (end)
@  (end)
@(end)
@(bind tdata @(transpose qdata))
@(bind fdata @(flatten (transpose data)))
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@{tdata " "}
@  (end)
@  (repeat)
@fdata
@  (end)
@(end)
```

```
$ txr soln.txr data
"0eij8401c "dbij8a015 "abij3b011 "59ij41015 "edij6801e
"59ij41015 "67ijb9011 "7fij70018 "f6ijae01e "pdij6801e
"21ij3e01c "b5ije001b "77ijf9010 "c4ij5801c "kdij6801e
"dbije401b "bdij3701d "e5ij64015 "dbij98012 "8cij57018
0eij8401c
dbij8a015
abij3b011
59ij41015
edij6801e
59ij41015
67ijb9011
7fij70018
f6ijae01e
pdij6801e
21ij3e01c
b5ije001b
77ijf9010
c4ij5801c
kdij6801e
dbije401b
bdij3701d
e5ij64015
dbij98012
8cij57018
```